# httpx AsyncClient -missing method prepare_request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, httpx

I am trying to port the "Prepared Request" example from this link: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/ using httpx AsnycClient.

```
from requests import Request, Session

s = Session()
req = Request('GET',  url, data=data, headers=headers)

prepped = s.prepare_request(req)

# do something with prepped.body
prepped.body = 'Seriously, send exactly these bytes.'

# do something with prepped.headers
prepped.headers['Keep-Dead'] = 'parrot'

resp = s.send(prepped,
    stream=stream,
    verify=verify,
    proxies=proxies,
    cert=cert,
    timeout=timeout
)

print(resp.status_code)
```

But I could not find any method to prepare the request in the httpx async lib.
In particular, it seems that "prepare_request" method is not implemented.

Can anyone tell me how do I prepare requests using AsyncClient?

Any hint is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One could use httpx.Request class to write an prepare_request factory.

```py
import httpx


def prepare_request(method, url, **kwargs):
    # a very simple factory
    return httpx.Request(method, url, **kwargs)


request = prepare_request("GET", "https://www.google.com")

client = httpx.Client()

response = client.send(request)

print(response, response.num_bytes_downloaded )
```

used sync client for demonstration only